# Java FX MVC multiple views

Tags: java, javafx, model-view-controller

I am using Java FX (required for a class project), and I am struggling to format my MVC so that I can load multiple views onto the stage (various scenes). I have a Controller as seen below that has 2 instances of View1.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;

public class Controller extends Application {

public int page = 0;

private View1 view2;
private View1 view1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage theStage) {
    view1 = new View1(theStage);
    view2 = new View1(theStage);
    new AnimationTimer() {
        public void handle(long currentNanoTime)
        {
            switch (page){
                case 0:
                    view1.update();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    view2.update();
                    break;
                default:
                    page = 0;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(33);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
    theStage.show();
  }

}
```

The problem occurs at the line `view2 = new View1(theStage);`. Without this line, the output is a large canvas with a background image. With that line, however, there is no background image it is just a blank canvas. Below is my View I simplified it as much as possible, just one background image to determine if it's loaded correctly. (I left the imports out in order to keep it concise, if needed I can add them back in)

```
public class View1 {
Stage theStage;
Group root;
Scene theScene;
Canvas canvas;

// value of the height and width of screen
int canvasWidth = 1000;
int canvasHeight = 800; 

GraphicsContext gc;

Image background;

//View1 constructor initialize the starting position for the image
//Called in controller
public View1(Stage theStage) {


    this.theStage = theStage;
    this.theStage.setTitle("Estuary Game");

    root = new Group();
    theScene = new Scene(root);
    this.theStage.setScene(theScene);

    canvas = new Canvas(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    root.getChildren().add(canvas);
    gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

    background = createImage("assets/mini-game-1.png");
}

//Read image from file and return
private Image createImage(String image_file) {
    Image img = new Image(image_file);
    return img;
}

//method used to repaint on the image and called in controller
public void update() {
    // draw background and sharkMove such like current
    gc.drawImage(background, 0, 0);

}

}
```

I am not sure I am tackling the multiple views correctly, my intentions are to just have multiple scenes but I wasn't sure how to structure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following structure (the following code is a one-file mre. Copy-paste it into `SwitchScene.java` and run) :

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SwitchScene extends Application {

    public int page = 0;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage theStage) {

        new Controller(theStage);
        theStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

class Controller {

    private final View1 view1,  view2;
    private final Stage stage;

    private static final String[] images = {
            "https://findicons.com/files/icons/345/summer/128/cake.png",
            "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/atyourservice/service-categories/128/Sweets-icon.png"
    };

    Controller(Stage stage) {
        this.stage = stage;
        view1 = new View1(images[0]);
        view2 = new View1(images[1]);
        swapScenes();
    }

    void swapScenes(){

        new AnimationTimer() {

            int page = 2;
            @Override
            public void handle(long currentNanoTime){
                switch (page){
                    case 2:
                        page = 1;
                        stage.setScene(new Scene(new Group(view1)));
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        page = 2;
                        stage.setScene(new Scene(new Group(view2)));
                        break;
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}

class View1 extends ImageView {

    public View1(String imagePath) {
        super(imagePath);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** a version of `View1` using canvas:

```
class View1 extends Group {

    public View1(String imagePath) {

        Image img = new Image(imagePath);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        getChildren().add(canvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. I feel like this is so close to what I need, however, in view I need to create a canvas and I need the variable gc (GraphicsContext) so I can populate the screen with a multitude of items. How can this be done without passing the stage or the scene to the view?

Comment: I am glad it helped. `View1` can be any `Node`. Fpr example it can be a `Group` or `Pane` .You can have `View1` extend `Node` and modify it to your needs.

Comment: I am getting an error that says `Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View2@7c69d5da[styleClass=root]is already set as root of another scene` I think this could be because I keep instantiating a new scene but im not sure.

Comment: It is not clear in what context. Are you are trying to set the same  root to two scenes ? For more help please post a new question and include an [mre].

Comment: Thank you for all of the help, I marked the solution as correct since this is what I needed. The second image, however, is not showing up. It fluctuates between a blank screen and the first view.